# How to replace entire element xml using xslt1.0

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

source file1:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<items>
    <item id='111'>
        <aa>111a</aa>
        <bb>111b</bb>
    </item>
    <item id='222'>
        <aa>222a</aa>
        <bb>222b</bb>
    </item>
    <item id='333'>
        <aa>333a</aa>
        <bb>333b</bb>
    </item>
</items>
```

source file2

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<items>
    <item id='222'>
        <aa>222aaaaa</aa>
        <bb>222bbbbb</bb>
    </item>
    <item id='444'>
        <aa>4444a</aa>
        <bb>4444b</bb>
    </item>
</items>
```

check the item[@id], if matched in file1, should replace the entire node to file1 from file2, if item[@id] = 444 can't find in file1, then append to file1.

the output xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<items>
    <item id='111'>
        <aa>111a</aa>
        <bb>111b</bb>
    </item>
    <item id='222'>
        <aa>222aaaaa</aa>
        <bb>222bbbbb</bb>
    </item>
    <item id='333'>
        <aa>333a</aa>
        <bb>333b</bb>
    </item>
    <item id='444'>
        <aa>4444a</aa>
        <bb>4444b</bb>
    </item>
</items>
```

below is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:param name="aa_file_path">file:///c:/Users/lijinxing/Desktop/test_1.xml</xsl:param>
    <xsl:variable name="aa_file" select="document($aa_file_path)"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="items/item">
            <xsl:variable name="id_var" select="@id"/>
            <xsl:variable name="content_var">
                <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:call-template name="aa">
                <xsl:with-param name="id_param" select="$id_var"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="content_param" select="$content_var"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:for-each select="$aa_file">
            <xsl:for-each select="items/item">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="aa">
        <xsl:param name="id_param"/>
        <xsl:param name="content_param"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$aa_file">
            <xsl:for-each select="items/item">
                <xsl:variable name="target_id_var" select="@id"/>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$target_id_var = $id_param">
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$content_param"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but below variable can't get the entire nodes

```
<xsl:variable name="content_var">
                <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
            </xsl:variable>
```

Comment: How important is the order of the items in the output? If it's not, you could copy the unmatched items from file1, then add **all** items from file2 - see:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31145220/xslt-to-augment-hadoop-config/31186191#31186191

Comment: no need to order, the answer is so great.Thanks.